# SQL Query doesn't work in different database collation

Tags: java, mysql

in localhost, i have a database with the collation `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`. and query finds the 'least two values' in row values and sums them up into another column.
the query worked perfectly with no errors.

here is the code below:

```
try{
    String sql="update jhs3 set Agregate=(SELECT LEAST(French_G,Rme_G,Ict_G,GhLang_G,BasicDesign_G) +" + 
"( SELECT  French_G AS s WHERE jhs3.ID = jhs3.ID UNION ALL " +
"  SELECT  Rme_G AS s WHERE jhs3.ID = jhs3.ID UNION ALL" +
"  SELECT  Ict_G AS s WHERE jhs3.ID = jhs3.ID UNION ALL" +
"  SELECT  GhLang_G AS s WHERE jhs3.ID = jhs3.ID UNION ALL" +
"  SELECT  BasicDesign_G AS s WHERE jhs3.ID = jhs3.ID" +
"  ORDER BY s LIMIT 1,1) AS result WHERE ID = jhs3.ID)";
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.execute();
     }
   catch(SQLException | NumberFormatException e){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }finally{
           try{
              pst.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
            }
        }
```

the columns are French_G, Rme_G, Ict_G, GHLang_G, BasicDesign_G, Agregate 
below is an example of records in database table.

- French_G + Rme_G + Ict_G + GhLang_G + BasicDesign_G + Agregate +
        10              15            5              20                   19
        14              10            2              19                   17
         5                8           15              12                   18

and below is an example of the query after execution:

- French_G + Rme_G + Ict_G + GhLang_G + BasicDesign_G + Agregate +
        10              15            5              20                   19                     15
        14              10            2              19                   17                     12
         5                8           15              12                   18                     13

i deployed the project to a live server but unfortunately i couldn't find the collation type `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` for the database so i used the collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
and since then the query doesn't work but rather throws the exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exeptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server for the right syntax to use
 near 'WHERE jhs3.ID = jhs3.ID UNION ALL SELECT Rme_G AS 's' WHERE jhs3.ID = jhs3.ID' at line 1
```

i tried putting braces on each select statement like this below:

```
   try{
    String sql="update jhs3 set Agregate=(SELECT LEAST(French_G,Rme_G,Ict_G,GhLang_G,BasicDesign_G) +" + 
"( SELECT  French_G AS s WHERE jhs3.ID = jhs3.ID) UNION ALL " +
" ( SELECT  Rme_G AS s WHERE jhs3.ID = jhs3.ID) UNION ALL" +
" ( SELECT  Ict_G AS s WHERE jhs3.ID = jhs3.ID) UNION ALL" +
" ( SELECT  GhLang_G AS s WHERE jhs3.ID = jhs3.ID) UNION ALL" +
" ( SELECT  BasicDesign_G AS s WHERE jhs3.ID = jhs3.ID" +
"  ORDER BY s LIMIT 1,1) AS result WHERE ID = jhs3.ID)";
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.execute();
     }
   catch(SQLException | NumberFormatException e){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }finally{
           try{
              pst.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
            }
        }
```

but still same error message. please all help will be appreciated

Comment: The error message comes from a different SQL qeury than the one you are showing. See the code.

Comment: @slaakso please the error message has been updated. used the same query for a different table and had the same problem.

Comment: Your error message stil does not match the code. Why not just print out the generated SQL and show that.

Comment: @slaakso , please i have updated the error message generated from the query execution

Comment: Your error message stil does not match the code. Why not just print out the generated SQL and show that.

Comment: please sir @slaakso , the error message above is generated and displayed in JOptionPane from the live host server. and that is exactly what is shown. unless you referring to a different error message. please advice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229404/discussion-between-rodney-nart-and-slaakso).